# Does Org-mode support RTL Languages like arabic

Tags: org-mode, arabic-support

Does Org-mode support RTL Languages like arabic ?

The objective is to prepare and typeset a book in arabic script and export it as PDF for print.

Comment: Emacs 24 supports [bidirectional text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Editing.html), and googling suggests org-mode should work too. Have you tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a correct RTL display you can add the following snippet to your init file:

```
(defun set-bidi-env ()
  "interactive"
  (setq bidi-paragraph-direction 'nil))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'set-bidi-env)
```

From [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Editing.html):

> The variable `bidi-paragraph-direction`, if `non-nil`, disables the dynamic determination of the base direction, and instead forces all paragraphs in the buffer to have the direction specified by its buffer-local value. The value can be either `right-to-left` or `left-to-right`. Any other value is interpreted as `nil`.

As for pdf export, orgmode handles this using latex. Latex have a rich language support and you can easily makes this work. You can read more about that [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-and-PDF-export.html).

Comment: How about the HTML export?